# Representing an Excel cell address in a formula using the string values of other Excel cells?

Tags: excel, eval, worksheet-function

Say I want the answer to this type of `formula = SUM(startcell:endcell)` but the `startcell` and `endcell` components change.

So instead of using `C1` directly in a formula to represent the value in cell `C1`, I want to be able to use whatever the values are in and `B1, B2, and B3` to construct something that can represent `C1` in a formula?

Perhaps a better way to ask the question is, Does Excel have something like Python's `eval()` ?

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Explaining Excel formulas in text is tedious ... I think an image is better

[image]

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I needed to get it to work for me I made a small change in how you described the formula that was in cell B3. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think that more useful is the address formula which allows you to build a cell address string from the inputs you have specified.  The notation is =ADDRESS(row_number, column_number,absolute_number_flag,bool_A1Style,sheet_text).

So for your example:
- To return Sheet1!R1C3 you would use =ADDRESS(B3,B2,,FALSE,B1)
- To return Sheet1!C1 you would use =ADDRESS(B3,B2,,TRUE,B1) or =ADDRESS(B3,B2,,,B1)

You can then use your INDIRECT function on this returned address.

Note if you wanted a dynamic range to be summed using the sum() function you could use two address calls to build the string for the whole range.

E.G. If you added the value of 5 in cells C3 and C4 of your example to specify row and column for your end cell you could have a formula of =ADDRESS(B4,B3,,,B2)&":"&ADDRESS(C4,C3) which would return 'Sheet1!'!$C$1:$E$5

I can't post images yet so hopefully this makes sense in text!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
formula = SUM(INDIRECT(B1),INDIRECT(B2),INDIRECT(B3))
```

And make more tests to see if you can work on ranges

Comment: B1... B3 in the OP are not addresses on its own, but the parts of only one address (sheet, column, row)